# error when error_reporting enabled in CE1.8

Tags: magento-1.8

when I set error_reporting to be E_ALL E_STRICT.
Magento backend barfs with this error which I can only see in the apache logs, I get a white screen on my dashboard.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Notice: Undefined index: CLIENT_IP  /includes/config.php(1) : runtime-created function(1) : eval()'d code(1) : eval()'d code(1) : eval()'d code(1) : eval()'d code on line 157 in app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php:245
```

Is it something to do with compiler? Looking at includes/config.php bit and presuming that is the case BUT compiler is turned off and cleared so I am wondering what is going on.
includes/config.php has nothing in it, just two commented compiler lines as expected.

Can anyone advise how to proceed working this out, I can't follow that eval().d code bit of the error message and I can't debug other issues because when I enable error reporting this gets triggered first.

Answer (score 0):

What happens:

1. you try to access an array key `CLIENT_IP`, most probably `$_SERVER['CLIENT_IP']` somewhere in your code
2. this key is not defined, therefore a notice is emited
3. This notice is transformed to an exception
4. which is not catched
5. so you have a white screen, `ini_set('display_errors', 0)` is set

So I would just search for `CLIENT_IP` in your code. The notice about eval() ist a bad one, if you ask me, some stupid developer/company/whatever either did really wrong, or they decided to uglify their code (Which is wrong too).

Comment: thanks for your reply, searching like that is a good idea and kind of obvious.  `in_set('display_errors',1);` is set, I still get a white screen.

Comment: `grep -r CLIENT_IP ./`  from magento root produces no results. Any other ideas?

Comment: grep for eval. Some module is base64 encoded :-/